# adding new elements to a select not always work in IE (jquery)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I have a strange problem.  Under IE sometimes the code below does not work.

It is supposed to call an url to fetch a json of elements.  It works all the time under Chrome but in IE sometimes I have to reload the page.

```
jQuery('#' + returnElementId).children().remove().end();
               for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++) {
                   jQuery('#' + returnElementId).append(jQuery("<option/>", {
                      value: response.data[i].id,
                      text: response.data[i].name
                  }));
               }
```

Comment: u r using jquery ajax to feach json data?

Comment: what jquery version u r using?

Comment: Yes I am using.  1.7.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#' + returnElementId).html('');

    $.each(response.data, function (i, entity) {
        $('#' + returnElementId).append($("<option />", { 'value': entity.id, 'text': entity.name }));
    });
```

for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/UFCF4/

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try and see if it behaves more stable.   Please  note that my code do work and even when it doesn't no error message is generated in Microsofts Console (developer tools).

Comment: It did not solve.  It works (just like mine) but under IE normally only after a reload.